# SWI Prolog - Cinema Entry Project - When I ask for a customers age, is doesn't write the correct information

Tags: prolog

I'm using SWI prolog, one of my tasks is to implement a simple cinema entry program using Prolog. Everything seems to working alright, but for the question 'Are you accompanied by an adult?' after the user had in putted 'No' for age 12, it should only write one film but it writes two.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
% Author:
% Date: 01/02/2016

%cust(Name,Age)
filmlisting:- write('Film Showings: '),nl,
    write('  - How to Lose Friends and Alienate People  (15)'),nl,
    write('  - Death Race (15)'),nl,
    write('  - Space Chimps (5)'),nl,
    write('  - The Chaser (18)'),nl,
    write('  - Get Smart (12)'),nl, %12A

        write('what is your age: '),nl,
    read(Age),nl,
    age(Age),nl.


    age(5):-
    write('Film that are available for your age: '),nl,
    write('  - space chimps').

    age(12):-write('Are you accomponied by adult '),nl,
    read(Yes),
    write('Films that are available for your age '),nl,
    write('  - Space Chimps'),nl,
    write('  - Get Smart').

    age(12):-write('Are you accomponied by adult '),nl,
    read(No),
    write('Films that are available for your age '),nl,
    write('  - Space Chimps').

    age(15):-write('Films that are available for your age: '),nl,
    write('  - How to Lose Friends and Alienate People'),nl,
    write('  - Death Race').

    age(18):-write('Films that are available for your age: '),nl,
    write('  - The Chaser').



%films
film('How to Lose Friends and Alienate People').
film('Death Race').
film('Space Chimps').
film('The Chaser').
film('Get Smart').

%ages
age(5).
age(12).
age(15).
age(18).


%age rating
agerating(5).%u
agerating(12).
agerating(15).
agerating(18).

%film and age rating combined
film_agerating('DeathRace',(15)).
film_agerating('How to Lose Friends and Alienate People',(15)).
film_agerating('Space Chimps',(5)).
film_agerating('The Chaser',(18)).
film_agerating('Get Smart',(12)).%12A

%sub categorising the films into different caterogies
get_kidsfilm:-
    film_agerating(X,5),
    format('~w ~s kids film ~n',[X," - "]).

get_supervisionfilm:-
    film_agerating(X,12),
    format('~w ~s supervisional film ~n',[X," - "]).

get_teenagefilm:-
    film_agerating(X,15),
    format('~w ~s teenage film ~n',[X," - "]).

get_adultfilm:-
    film_agerating(X,18),
    format('~w ~s adult film ~n',[X," - "]).

get_allfilms:-
    film_agerating(X,18),
    format('~w ~s 18 ~n',[X," - "]),
    film_agerating(Y,15),
    format('~w ~s 15 ~n',[Y," - "]),
        film_agerating(Z,12),
    format('~w ~s 12 ~n',[Z," - "]),
        film_agerating(A,5),
    format('~w ~s U ~n',[A," - "]).
```

Basically the issue which at hand here, when the user has entered age '12' and put 'Yes' to are you accompanied by an adult it should write the two films which are available for his age. However, if the user enters 'No', then it should only display the one film.
But! For some reason, it keeps displaying the two films and not the one.

Response:

filmlisting.
Film Showings: 
  - How to Lose Friends and Alienate People  (15)
  - Death Race (15)
  - Space Chimps (5)
  - The Chaser (18)
  - Get Smart (12)
what is your age: 
|: 12.

Are you accomponied by adult 
|: Yes.
Films that are available for your age 
  - Space Chimps
  - Get Smart

filmlisting.
Film Showings: 
  - How to Lose Friends and Alienate People  (15)
  - Death Race (15)
  - Space Chimps (5)
  - The Chaser (18)
  - Get Smart (12)
what is your age: 
|: 12.

Are you accomponied by adult 
|: No.
Films that are available for your age 
  - Space Chimps
  - Get Smart

See the No, is still showing two answers.

If anyone could be of any assistance would really greatful.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking variables for concrete atoms. When you compile the program, SWI-Prolog already tells you:

```
Warning: /var/folders/c8/t3slw2096zddgymjw5zwq1tc0000gn/T/ediprolog1064499_:21:
    Singleton variables: [Yes]
Warning: /var/folders/c8/t3slw2096zddgymjw5zwq1tc0000gn/T/ediprolog1064499_:27:
    Singleton variables: [No]
```

Change these variables to the atoms `yes` and `no`, and your program will behave as expected.

One more important point: Your program currently depends heavily on side-effects. Try to find a **more declarative** way to describe an interaction. This will allow you to actually write **test cases** for your program! Separate the declarative reasoning from actual IO for a solution that can be used in more directions.

For example, wouldn't it be nice to actually find out **which films** need being accompanied by an adult? If you choose a suitable representation for the available knowledge, this will become possible.

Comment: Hello, appreciate your reply thank you it works. However, for the 'Are you accompanied by an adult'. When I enter 'no'. It duplicates the question again asking 'are you accompanied by an adult', when I put 'no' this time it works. Any way to make it working first time, without it asking the question again.

Comment: It will be tempting for you to **commit** to one of the branches, using impure constructs like if-then-else. But this will lead you **away** from the declarative benefits that a pure solution will give you, so **stay pure**! You can stay pure with a simple auxiliary predicate like: `answer(yes) :- <clauses for the 'yes' case>. answer(no) :- <clauses for the 'no' case>'`, and then simply doing: `read(Answer), answer(Answer)` to invoke the auxiliary predicate. Advantage: The auxiliary predicate can be used in **all directions**, and still generates all answers for `answer(What)`.